# Manage NUGET Packages menu missing after update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, package-managers

I have recently updated the package manager (VSIX extension) for NUGET to version 3.5.
Afterwards I noticed the UI is missing:

[image]

Normally there is a 3rd menu item available 
[image]

(right between console and settings menu items), which opens the dialog for searching, installing, updating and removing nuget packages.

I tried to uninstall/reinstall it, but had no luck.
Also looking in Google and on the NuGET site did not help me finding an answer.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Maybe you should also tag the visual studio version. (2015 I guess?)

Comment: Yes, VS 2015 Enterprise

Comment: What third menu item is missing? I only see Package Manager Console and Package Manager Settings menu items in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Yes, and there should be a 3rd menu item, the Package Manager Frontend (UI) which is missing. I can't remember its exact name but it is the dialog allowing you to search nuget packages, install, uninstall and update them.

Comment: The Manage NuGet Packages for Solution menu is the third menu. That is only shown if a solution is open in Visual Studio 2015. It is also available if you right click the solution in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: @MattWard - Yes, you are right. The update I did required a restart of Visual Studio and when I opened the Tools / Nuget Manager Menu after the restart I did not notice that the solution was closed.

Comment: @MattWard - many thanks. If you copy your comment into an answer, you can get some reputation points. :-)

Comment: Ok - I did that now to make the answer more visible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer provided by [Matt Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268874/matt-ward), as taken from the comments:

"The **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution** menu is the third menu. That is only shown, if a **solution is open** in Visual Studio 2015. It is also available if you **right click the solution** in the Solution Explorer."

Another possibility why it is missing is because you haven't created a solution file and just opened the project. Create a solution file and then re-load the solution in Visual Studio (thank you [DeveloperDan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381082/developerdan) for this hint).

*(**Note:** The NUGET update I did required a restart of Visual Studio, and when I opened the Tools / Nuget Manager Menu **after the restart** I did not notice that the solution was closed.)*

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT sure, but note there is a delay (I think 20 hours) before you are able to mark the answer. This morning, I could not do it - I had to wait.

Comment: I had opened a project without clicking the solution (sln) file and Nuget Gui was missing. I closed the project, opened via the sln file and Nuget Gui re-appeared.

Answer (score 40):

Maybe the option wasn't showing because the project was running?

Comment: Yes, that is another possibility.

Comment: ah the quirks of visual studio *sigh*

Comment: menu option appeared after stopping debugger VS 2019

Comment: This made me laugh